# How to remove only symbols from string in dart

Tags: regex, dart, flutter

I want to remove all special symbols from string and have only words in string 
I tried this but it gives same output only

```
main() {
    String s = "Hello, world! i am 'foo'";
    print(s.replaceAll(new RegExp('\W+'),'')); 
}
```

output : `Hello, world! i am 'foo'`
expected : `Hello world i am foo`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[The docs for the RegExp class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/RegExp-class.html) state that you should use *raw* strings (a string literal prefixed with an `r`, like `r"Hello world"`) if you're constructing a regular expression that way. This is particularly necessary where you're using escapes.

In addition, your regex is going to catch spaces as well, so you'll need to modify that. You can use `RegExp(r"[^\s\w]")` instead - that matches any character that's not whitespace or a word character

Comment: thanks that worked but it also removed spaces can you tell me on how to not to remove spaces ?

Answer (score 56):

There are two issues:

- `'\W'` is not a valid escape sequence, to define a backslash in a regular string literal, you need to use `\\`, or use a *raw* string literal (`r'...'`)
- `\W` regex pattern matches any char that is not a word char including whitespace, you need to use a negated character class with word and whitespace classes, `[^\w\s]`.

Use

```
void main() {
  String s = "Hello, world! i am 'foo'";
  print(s.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[^\w\s]+'),''));
}
```

Output: `Hello world i am foo`.

**Fully Unicode-aware solution**

Based on [What's the correct regex range for javascript's regexes to match all the non word characters in any script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62772689/3832970) post, bearing in mind that `\w` in Unicode aware regex is equal to `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`, you can use the following in Dart:

```dart
void main() {
  String s = "Hęllo, wórld! i am 'foo'";
  String regex = r'[^\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}\s]+';
  print(s.replaceAll(RegExp(regex, unicode: true),''));
}
// => Hęllo wórld i am foo
```

Comment: worked and additionaly ive added .replaceall("_","") at the end

Comment: @RajeshJr. You may merge that into 1 regex: `.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'(?:_|[^\w\s])+', '')`

Comment: Simple but it will replace non-English 'LETTERS' as well

Comment: @EhabReda Updated with a fully Unicode aware solution.

Comment: How to remove line breaks too? I'm getting "%0D%0A" when it's encoded further down the code.

Comment: @SarahK These are matched with `\s`. If you want to only keep regular spaces (`\x20`), then simply replace `\s` with a regular space, i.e. `[^\w ]+`

Answer (score 22):

I found this question looking for how to remove a symbol from a string. For others who come here wanting to do that:

```
final myString = 'abc=';
final withoutEquals = myString.replaceAll(RegExp('='), ''); // abc
```

Comment: i'm getting bad results when replacing '.' with '' in a string of numbers "32.151"

Comment: @A.easazadeh, That is because the `.` dot character means [match any single character](https://medium.com/@suragch/how-to-match-any-single-character-with-a-regular-expression-421b9fc13681) in regular expressions. Thus, in your example every single character is matched and replaced. If you only want to match the literal `.` dot, then you need to escape it as `RegExp('\\.')` or as `RegExp(r'\.')` or as `RegExp('[.]')`.

Answer (score 8):

Removing characters "," from string:

```
String myString = "s, t, r";
myString = myString.replaceAll(",", ""); // myString is "s t r"
```

Answer (score 7):

First solution

```
s.replaceAll(RegExp(",|!|'"), "");    // The | operator works as OR
```

Second solution

```
s.replaceAll(",", "").replaceAll("!", "").replaceAll("'", "");
```