# What's the correct regex range for javascript's regexes to match all the non word characters in any script?

Tags: javascript, regex

In python or PHP a simple regex such as `/\W/gu` matches any non-word character in any script, in javascript however it matches `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`, what are the correct ranges to match the same characters as python and PHP?

https://regex101.com/r/yhNF8U/1/

Comment: @Mandy8055 I want to match anything but word characters just like it works in php and in python (if you click the regex101 link you can see how different languages match that regex)

Comment: You could test the below character properties on [regexpal](https://www.regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Generic solution***

Mathias Bynens suggests to follow the [UTS18](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#word) recommendation and thus a Unicode-aware `\W` will look like:

```
[^\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]
```

Please note the comment for the suggested Unicode property class combination:

> **This is only an approximation to Word Boundaries (see [b](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#b) below). The
> Connector Punctuation is added in for programming language
> identifiers, thus adding "_" and similar characters.**

***More considerations***

The `\w` construct (and thus its `\W` counterpart), when matching in a Unicode-aware context, matches similar, but somewhat different set of characters across regex engines.

For example, here is [Non-word character: `\W`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#non-word-character-w) .NET definition: `[^\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Mn}\p{Pc}\p{Lm}]`, where `\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}` can be contracted to a sheer `\p{L}` and the pattern is thus equal to `[^\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Mn}\p{Pc}]`.

In Android (see [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern#unicode-support)), `[^\p{Alpha}\p{gc=Mn}\p{gc=Me}\p{gc=Mc}\p{Digit}\p{gc=Pc}\p{IsJoin_Control}]`, where `\p{gc=Mn}\p{gc=Me}\p{gc=Mc}` can be just written as `\p{M}`.

In PHP PCRE, `\W` matches `[^\p{L}\p{N}_]`.

[Rexegg cheat sheet](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#classes) defines Python 3 `\w` as "*Unicode letter, ideogram, digit, or underscore*", i.e. `[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Nd}_]`.

You may roughly decompose `\W` as `[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}]`:

```
/[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}]/gu
```

where

- `[^` - is the start of the negated character class that matches a single char other than:

  - `\p{L}` - any Unicode letter
  - `\p{N}` - any Unicode digit
  - `\p{M}` - a diacritic mark
  - `\p{Pc}`  - a connector punctuation symbol
- `]` - end of the character class.

Note it is `\p{Pc}` class that matches an underscore.

**NOTE** that `\p{Alphabetic}` (`\p{Alpha}`) includes all letters matched by `\p{L}`, plus *letter numbers* matched by `\p{Nl}` (e.g. `Ⅻ` – a character for the roman number `12`), plus some other symbols matched with `\p{Other_Alphabetic}` (`\p{OAlpha}`).

Other variations:

- `/[^\p{L}0-9_]/gu` - to just use `\W` that is aware of Unicode letters only
- `/[^\p{L}\p{N}_]/gu` - (PCRE `\W` style) to just use `\W` that is aware of Unicode letters and digits only.

Note that Java's `(?U)\W` will match a mix of what `\W` matches in PCRE, Python and .NET.

Comment: I don't know why this answer was downvoted; this doesn't work on regex101, however it seems to work on my code, I'll test it a little more on my code and if it works with every reasonable input I'll accept it

Comment: @thelmuxkriovar regex101 does not support Unicode property classes in JS regex flavor. It is a bug that is only regex101 related.

Comment: @thelmuxkriovar please Check [this](https://github.com/firasdib/Regex101/issues/1333) issue.

Comment: Well explained and as always very educational ++

Comment: @Thefourthbird Unfortunately, it is pretty concise. This topic deserves a whole book chapter. I made tests before, to see what Unicode-aware `\w` matches in different engines, but I lost most of the details. The main idea though is to design your own character class that only contains the Unicode property classes you need.

Comment: Your regex reads `\p{M}`, but you detail `\p{Mn}`, is that a typo?

Comment: @sp00m Thank you for spotting the inconsistency, I meant to say `\p{M}`. I noticed it is best to use the whole mark class, especially when dealing with languages like Hebrew, or Indic languages.