# Is there equivalent regex value "W" for Unicode characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex that doesn't account for Chinese Unicode characters.  I'd like to include Chinese words.  Anyone know how to do this in javascript?

```
\w+|"(?:\\"|[^"])+"
```

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: For Java, just add `(?U)` at the start. In JavaScript, use `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]` and `u` flag. In PHP, add `u` flag. In Python 3, .NET `\w` is already Unicode-aware. In Ruby, maybe `[\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}]` / `[\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}]` will do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew javascript

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62772641/whats-the-correct-regex-range-for-javascripts-regexes-to-match-all-the-non-wor/62772689#62772689. `\w` is the opposite of `\W`, so, you need to remove `^` after `[` in the top solution.