# regular expression to match hashtags in both left to right and right to left languages

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I use the following code to find words that start with hashtags:

```
var regex = /(?:^|\W)#(\w+)(?!\w)/g;
```

but it only matches the English words and it can not match hashtags in other languages such as arabic. so, how can I find hashtags in a text like this:

> this is a simple #text
>  هذا #نص بسیط

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following regex alternation:

```
(?<!\S)#\S+|\S+#(?!\S)
```

### Demo

Answer (score 4):

If the value after the # should not contain a # itself, you could use a negated character class `[^\s#]` matching any character except `#` either way around using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|`

The value is in capture group 1.

```
(?:^|\s)(#[^\s#]+|[^\s#]+#)(?=$|\s)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PLjlJ3/1)

```js
const pattern = /(?:^|\s)(#[^\s#]+|[^\s#]+#)(?=$|\s)/;
[
  "this is a simple #test1",
  "هذا #نص بسیط",
  "test #test2#",
  "test #test3#test3",
  "test ##test4",
  "test test5##",
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(pattern);
  if (m) console.log(m[1]);
});
```

Comment: Consider replacing `(?:^|\s)` with just `(?<!\S)` ... it's a useful trick, and possibly would outperform the alternation version you used.  +1 to you anyway.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I know :-), but to keep it backwards compatible with older browsers so the OP and future readers of the question have different options and to keep our answers different I used `(?:^|\s)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Still, you should consider using `(?=$|\s)` / `(?!\S)` rather than `(?:$|\s)` to ensure consecutive matches are found.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

Bearing in mind that a Unicode aware `\w` can be represented with `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]` (see [What's the correct regex range for javascript's regexes to match all the non word characters in any script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62772641)), the direct Unicode equivalent of your pattern is

```
const uw = String.raw`[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`; // uw = Unicode \w
const regex = new RegExp(`(?<!${uw})#(${uw}+)(?!${uw})`, "gu");
```

Now, to match both directions, you may use

```
const regex = new RegExp(`(?<!${uw})(?:#(${uw}+)|${uw}+#)(?!${uw})`, "gu");
                                  ^_________^_______^
```

That is, a non-capturing group with an alternation `|` char is used with two alernatives, that match `#` + Unicode word chars on the right, or Unicode word chars and then a `#` on the right. **Details**:

- `(?<!${uw})` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a Unicode word char immediately on the left
- `(?:#(${uw}+)|${uw}+#)` - a non-capturing group that matches either

  - `#(${uw}+)` - a `#` char followed with one or more Unicode word chars
  - `|` - or
  - `${uw}+#` - one or more Unicode word chars followed with a `#` char
- `(?!${uw})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a Unicode word char immediately on the right.

The `g` flag ensures multiple matches and `u` enables the Unicode property classes support in the pattern.

A JavaScript demo:

```js
const strings = ["this is a simple #text #text2", "هذا #نن*&ص بسیط","#نص2 هذا #نص بسیط"];
const uw = String.raw`[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`; // uw = Unicode \w
const regex = new RegExp(`(?<!${uw})(?:#(${uw}+)|${uw}+#)(?!${uw})`, "gu");
strings.forEach( string => console.log(string, '=>', string.match(regex)))
```