# Block script character using regex

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, ecmascript-6

I want to block all character that has possible script such as `#$%^&*<>~\[]{}@.,?`|/

I cannot use `^[a-zA-Z]([\w -]*[a-zA-Z])?$/i.test(value)` because at my application I have spanish lang support which includes alphabets like ę Æ and so on....

Now how can i achieve this forming a Regex? Can anyone help me here? New to RegEx

I want to block special character specified above. characters which can potential form a script. For restriction of user input purpose

Comment: Sorry, what is the problem? Do you want to match a string that is fully composed of non-special chars?

Comment: “Block” them for what purpose? And what do single characters have to do with “script”?

Comment: I want to block special character specified above. characters which can potential form a script. For restriction of user input purpose. 
@CBroe

Comment: Yes, but what is the _context_? While this might make sense for specific value such as maybe a user name, it makes much little sense if we are talking just about any free-form text input here. You say you are worried about characters from the Spanish language, but then you want to block simple punctuation characters such as dot or coma already - so the input of an actual natural language text with multiple sentences would be impossible in English already. So, what is the _context_?

Comment: And why do you think anything that _could_ form a “script”, needed blocking in the first place? If Stackoverflow did that, we could hardly have any discussion about code here at all. But those _don’t_ get blocked here, and yet this site is not constantly in danger of hacking … So, also in that regard, _what_ is the context?

Comment: @CBroe I have such use case, that's why posted the question. Stuck with the solution

Comment: So just use a negated character class containing all those “bad” ones then?

Comment: are you aware that react already does this for you? are you using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`? again,we can't answer your question without any context!

Comment: I guess you just want to make your second regex Unicode aware. Try `/^\p{L}(?:[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}\s-]*\p{L})?$/iu.test(value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/^[a-zA-Z]([\w -]*[a-zA-Z])?$/i` regex only matches ASCII characters.

If you plan to make it work with Spanish language, you need to make it Unicode aware.

Bearing in mind that a Unicode aware `\w` can be represented with `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]` (see [What's the correct regex range for javascript's regexes to match all the non word characters in any script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62772641)) and the Unicode letter pattern is `\p{L}`, the direct Unicode equivalent of your pattern is

```js
/^\p{L}(?:[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}\s-]*\p{L})?$/iu.test(value)
```

I also replaced the regular space with `\s` to match any kind of Unicode whitespace.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\p{L}` - any Unicode letter
- `(?:[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}\s-]*\p{L})?` - an optional occurrence of any 0 or more Unicode word chars (letter, diacritic, number, connector punctuation  (like `_`), join control chars), whitespace or hyphens followed with a single Unicode letter
- `$`  - end of string.

Comment: What if I don't want to put space after the input value. Meaning if I put `example` works but if I put `example ` then it shows error. I want to allow space after `example ` like this. Other than that works great!

Comment: @ZeusCarl Do you mean you have [this](https://regex101.com/r/6wb8Ri/1) where `example` has trailing spaces and you want to allow them? Add `\s*` at the end. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6wb8Ri/2) where I am using a regular space instead of `\s` since the demo is run against a single  multiline text.

Comment: Thanks, This is what I wanted.

Comment: What if I want to allow numbers?? like `example3` is causing error but I want to allow such value inputs.

Comment: @ZeusCarl Then change `\p{L}` into `[\p{L}\p{N}]`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6wb8Ri/3). If you have a list of specific requirements, please share. Fixing example after example is too time consuming.

Comment: Like Only thing is After `example- ` when things are allowed and then when it comes at the end it shows error. So anything which is allowed and last value like `example-` or `example_` it should not generate error.

Comment: So, all allowed chars are allowed everywhere and in any succession? Just use `/^(?:[^\p{P}\p{S}]|[_-])*$/u` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6wb8Ri/6)). Or, just use `/^\p{L}[\p{L}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation} -]*$/u`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/6wb8Ri/7) (where the first char must be a letter, and the rest is any zero or more of allowed chars).