# A regular expression to find all corresponding song verses by a word or its part

Tags: javascript, regex, full-text-search, wildcard, regex-lookarounds

I have a large (more than 852000 lines) text file with song verses and each of them is preceded by a number, such as `1.`, `134-20.` or `1231.`, but not one led by a hashtag like `#45345`. Each verse may contain four or more lines. There are also variations of lines, which should be ignored for now.

This is my code I have been struggling with no good results so far:

```
$.ajax({url:"LD.txt",dataType:'text',success:function(data){
//var lines=data.match(/(.*)\r\n(^[A-Z].*)+/mg);
var lines=data.match(/(.*)(^[A-Z].*)+/mg);
for(var i=0;i<50/*lines.length*/;i++){
var line=lines[i].replace("\r\n","");console.log(i+" "+line);
}}});
```

This is a part of utf-8 text file:

```
/* 1970  #1.#  PAR DZIESMĀM UN DZIEDAŠANU
#1. Dziesmas un dziedašana vispāriga tautas manta un cilvēka mūža pavadoņi.
1.Dziesmas visai Latvijai kopeja manta. */

15.
Dziesmiņ' mana, kā dziedama,
Ne ta mana pamanita;
Vecā māte pamācija,
Aizkrāsnē tupedama.
#279a.

16.
Māci, māte, man' dziedāt,
Māc' ar vienu Dieva dziesmu,
Ko dziedās dvēselite,
Pie Dieviņa aizgājuse.
#15b,27b.
16-1.
Māci mani, māmuliņa,
Jele vienu Dieva dziesmu,
Ko dziedās dvēselite,
Dieva duru dagājuse.
#33d.
4:[Dieva durvim pieiedama].
#137e.
4:[Debes durvim piegājusi].
#111d.
4:[Pie Dieviņa debesīs].
#137c.
16-2.
Māci mani, māmulite,
Māci kādu Dieva dziesmu,
Ko dziedašu, nogājuse
Pie Dieviņa nama durvu.
Ne Dieviņis iekšā laida,
Ne eņģeļi vārtus vēra.
#218.
16-3.
Tēvis, tēvis, māte, māte,
Mācat mani pātaros;
Es āziešu pie Dieviņa
Bez neviena pātariņa.
#172i.

17.
Dzied', māsiņ, dzied', māsiņ,
Vedīs tautas šoruden;
Atstāj savas skaistas dziesmas
Jaunajām māsiņām.
#324a.

18.
Es dziedāt nedziedaju (nevareju),
Sacīt vien pasaciju,
Sacīìt vien pasaciju
Jaunajām māsiņām.
#137d,324a.

19.
Saki dziesmas, bāleliņ,
Jaunakām (Mazajām) māsiņām,
Tu staigaji tālu zemi,
Tu dziesmiņu daudz dzirdeji (zinaji).
#126c,141.
3:[Tu bij' tālu izstaigajis],
#354,367.
19-1.
Stāsti dziesmas, bāleliņ,
Jaunakai māsiņai,
Tu bij' tālu izstaigajis,
Tu bij' daudzi izredzejis.
#137d.

20.
Dziedat, meitas, ar manim,
Man bij (ir) daudz skaistu dziesmu;
Pa vienai salasiju,
Svešu zemi (Svešas zemes) staigadams.
#28d,68a,335 N% 107,325c,400.
1:[Dziedait], meitas ar manim,
#137b N% 2209,391 N% 33.
1:[Dziedait], meitas, ar manim,
2:[Ar ir] daudz skaistu dziesmu;
#41c N% 3 pag 196.
1:Dziedat, meitas [ar maniem],
#6c,68d,88b,95d,104,121n.
2:Man bij (ir) daudz [svešu dziesmu];
#111c,325e,379.
4:Svešu zemi (Svešas zemes) [staigajot].
#98a,226f,314,407b.
4:[Tāļas zemes] staigadams.
#91c,122b.
4:[ļaužu zemi] staigadams.
#3b.
20-1.
Dziedat, meitas, ar manim,
Man ir gan greznu dziesmu;
Svešas zemes izstaigaju,
Pa vienai lasidams.
#293a.
20-2.
Palīdziet man dziedāt,
Man bij daudz skaistu dziesmu;
Pa vienai salasiju
Pa pasauli staigadams.
#91c.
20-3.
Mīlit mani jūs, māsiņas,
Man bij daudz svešu dziesmu,
Es atnācu pār jūriņu
Svešā dziesmu laiviņā.
#146a.
20-4.
Es staigaju tāļu zemi
Man dziesmišu vācelite;
Es savām māsiņām
Svešas dziesmas skandinašu.
#126c.

21.
Skaisti dziedu dziedadama,
Gauži raudu raudadama:
Bāliņš skaisti dziedenaja,
Tautiets gauži raudenaja.
#28f.

22.
Kad es dziedu, koši (grazni) dziedu,
Kad es raudu, žēli raudu.
Kā es koši (grazni) nedziedašu,
Māŗa dziesmu teicejiņa;
Kā es žēli neraudašu,
Kad es biju (augu) sērdienite.
#156,161c,164c,173,335 N% 208.
/*Bitnera L. ļaužu dz.kā motto.*/
2:[Kad raudaju], žēli raudu.
#188.
1:Kad es [dziežu], koši (grazni) [dziežu],
2:Kad es [raužu], žēli [raužu].
4:[Māres dziesmu] teicejiņa;
#185c.
4:[Māras dziesmu] teicejiņa;
#391 N% .

22.
Mīļa Laima, Dieva meit',
Nāc dziesmiņas darināt:
Teic dziesmiņas, dziedi pati
Par jauniem, par veciem.
#335 N% 66.

23.
Teic dziesmiņu (dziesmiņas), sērdienite,
Tu dziesmiņu daudz zinaji;
Ne tev tēva, ne māmiņas,
Dziesmiņās (Dziesmās vien) remdejies.
#10,28d,41c N% 41 pag 196, 68d, 119a, 174c, 184, 224d N% 41, 229a, 276c, 281c, 295a, 319c, 364, 379, 391 N% 8, 403.
4:[Dziesmiņām] remdejies.
#215b.
1:[Dzied' dziesmiņu], sērdienite,
#73b,377.
1:Teic dziesmiņu (dziesmiņas), [bārenite],
#98a,157,401.
2:Tu dziesmiņu [dievszingan];
#156,267b.
2:Tu dziesmiņu [dievsungan];
#88b.
23-1.
Teic man dziesmas, sērdienite,
Tu dziesmiņu daudz zinaji;
Tev nav tēva, māmuliņas,
Dziesmiņās remdejies.
#89b,161c,171a.
4:[Dziesmiņām] remdejies.
#176a N% 3706.
4:[Tu dziesmās] remdejies.
#278c.
3:[Tev nomira tēvs, māmiņa],
#152a.
23-2.
Saki dziesmas, bārenite,
Tev ir daudzi skaistu dziesmu:
Tev nav tēva, māmuliņas,
Dziesmas vien darinaji.
#311a.

24.
Teic man dziesmas, meža meita,
Tu dziesmiņu daudz zinaji,
Tev pateica lakstigala,
Krūmiņā sēdedama.
#214c,325c,348.
1:Teic man dziesmas, [meža māte],
#22h,111d.

25.
Visas manas labas dziesmas
Ceļa vidu aizgājušas;
Gan es citas salasišu
Svešu zemi staigadams.
#73b.

26.
Visas dziesmas izdziedatas,
Kur mēs citas dabusim?
Iesim dziesmu kambarī,
Tur mēs citas dabusim.
#6c,18,379,410.
3:Iesim dziesmu [krodziņā],
#172i,190f.
1:[Ta dziesmiņa pagalam],
#41c.
5:[Tur sēd divas jaunas meitas,]
6:[Dziesmas vien rakstidamas;]
7:[Ko ta viena izrakstija,]
8:[To ta otra izdziedaja.]
#379.
5:[Tur stāveja jaunas meitas],
7:Ko ta viena [nodziedaja],
8:To ta otra [pierakstija],
#68a,335 N% 124.
5:Tur sēd [divi] jaunas meitas,
7:Ko ta viena [sarakstija],
#41c N% 1 pag 195.
26-1.
Ta ziņģite pagalam,
Kur mēs citu dabusim?
Iesim ziņģu krodziņā,
Tur mēs citu dabusim;
Tur bij divas jumpraviņas,
Ziņģes vien darinaja.
#158.
2:Kur mēs citu [dabuisim]?
4:Tur mēs citu [dabuisim];
5:Tur bij [viena jumpraviņa],
#149a N% 1479.
1:[To ziņģiti pabeidzām];
7:[Ko ta viena sadomaja],
8:[To ta otra uzrakstija].
#401.
5:[Tur sēdeja trīs jumpravas,]
6:[Ziņģes vien darinaja;]
7:[Ko tās divas izziņģeja,]
8:[To trešā sarakstija.]
#325e.

/* 4.Dziesmu pūra pielocišana un bagatiba. */

27.
Bāliņos dzīvodama
Dziesmas tinu kamolī (kamolā);
Kad aizgāju (izgāju, nogāju) tautiņās,
Pa vienai šķetinaju.
#401.
4:[Tad vaļā] šķetinaju.
#137d.
1:[Kad es augu bāliņos],
#379,207r.
1:[Kad es augu pie māmiņas],
4:Pa vienai [risinaju].
#230.
1:[Pie māmiņas dzīvodama]
#19d,264c.
1:[Jauns būdams ganos gāju]
4:[No kamoļa] šķetinaju.
#319b N% 309,391 N% 29,109b.
1:[Kad es maza ganos gāju],
#19c.
1:[Pie bāliņa ganos gāju]
4:Pa vienai [risinaju].
#223b.
1:[Kad es biju jauna meita],
#41a,352,389.
4:Pa vienai [ritinaju].
#241f.

27-1.
Es satinu savas dziesmas
Baltā diega kamolī (kamolā);
Kad aizgāju tautiņās,
Pa vienai ritinaju.
#264g,363.
1:Es [ietinu] savas dziesmas
4:Pa vienai [risinaju].
#207m.
3:[Brāļam jāju vedibās],
#232a.
27-2.
Visas savas skaistas dziesmas
Es satinu kamolā,
Kad izgāju tautiņās,
Pa vienai šķetinaju.
#112a.
27-3.
Visas dziesmas izdziedatas,
Nu satinu kamolī;
Kad es iešu tautiņās,
Pa vienai ritinašu.
#219b.
27-4.
Man bij dziesmu kamolits
Smalkā lagzdu krūmiņā;
Kad izgāju (aizgāju) tautiņās,
Pa vienai ritinaju.
#22h.
4:Pa vienai [tecinaju].
#379,412,408 N% 758.
27-5.
Kad es biju jauna meita,
Man bij dziesmu vācelite,
Kad es gāju (aizgāju) tautiņās,
Pa vienai ritinaju.
#172q,196a.
1:[Man iedeva māmulite]
2:[Mazu dziesmu vāceliti],
#181c.
27-6.
Man bij dziesmu vācelite
Smalku nātru krūmiņā;
Kad aizgāju tautiņās,
Pa vienai izdziedaju.
#298d.
2:[Skaidienā glabajama];
4:Pa vienai [darinaju].
#379.
27-7.
Man dziesmiņu trīs pūriņi
Brāļ' apeņu dārziņā;
Kad aiziešu tautiņās,
Pa vienai izdziedašu.
#196i.
```

The javascript solution I am looking for is such where in the text input when exact word `dziedama` is provided, the results should be returned as

```
15. Dziesmiņ' mana, kā <b>dziedama</b>, Ne ta mana pamanita; Vecā māte pamācija, Aizkrāsnē tupedama.
```

I.e., the preceding number (which can be even several lines above, e.g., `23-2.` with following verse lines, as when searching `darinaji`) above of the verse part which contains the searched part + "tab" + verse with the searched part of word in bold.

If one provides a part of the word with asterisk `dzie*`, the results should look like this showing the full word in bold.

```
15. <b>Dziesmiņ'</b> mana, kā <b>dziedama</b>, Ne ta mana pamanita; Vecā māte pamācija, Aizkrāsnē tupedama.
16. Māci, māte, man' <b>dziedāt</b>, Māc' ar vienu Dieva <b>dziesmu</b>, Ko <b>dziedās</b> dvēselite, Pie Dieviņa aizgājuse.
16-1.   Māci mani, māmuliņa, Jele vienu Dieva <b>dziesmu</b>, Ko <b>dziedās</b> dvēselite, Dieva duru dagājuse.
...
```

In similar way it should look for asterisk in begining of the word `*esmu`, returning verses that contain either `dziesmu`, `iesmu`, `Dievadziesmu` etc. with variable length hidden behind the asterisk `*` in any part of the word.

If `dzied?` is written in the query besides letters, it should return verses that have either `dziedu`, `dziedi` or alike, i.e. with one utf-8 character hidden behind the `?`, which can be put in any part of the word.

If the search query is within double quotes like `vienu Dieva`, it should look for the exact word sequence in the verses.

It should be available to search the diacritics-full text, also by providing diacritics-less normalized characters.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the regex to match an entire verse starting with a number on a line by itself that contains the complete word `xxxxx` should be:

`^[0-9]+\.$(?:.(?!^[0-9]+\.$))+\b(xxxxx)\b.*?(?=^[0-9]+\.$)` with the flags `gmsu`

Where:

- `^[0-9]+\.$` matches a line with a number
- `(?:.(?!^[0-9]+\.$))+` matches characters that aren't followed by a line with a number
- `\b(xxxxx)\b` matches `xxxxx` as a complete word
- `.*?(?=^[0-9]+\.$)` matches the smallest amount that is followed by a line with a number

But there are problems: `\b` is defined to assert a position at a word boundary: `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`  `\W` and `\w` are defined to be `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` and `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` respectively.  But that doesn't support Unicode at all.

According to [What's the correct regex range for javascript's regexes to match all the non word characters in any script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62772641/whats-the-correct-regex-range-for-javascripts-regexes-to-match-all-the-non-wor) the `\W` equivalent for Unicode would be `[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}]` so using that same logic `\w` would be `[\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}]`.

So if we use look-arounds with those Unicode patterns instead of `\b` the regex to match an entire verse starting with a number on a line by itself that contains `xxxxx` should be:

`^[0-9]+\.$(?:.(?!^[0-9]+\.$))+(?<=^|[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}])(xxxxx)(?=$|[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}]).*?(?=^[0-9]+\.$)` with the flags `gmsu`

Where:

- `^[0-9]+\.$` matches a line with a number
- `(?:.(?!^[0-9]+\.$))+` matches characters that aren't followed by a line with a number
- `(?<=^|[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}])` matches a left word boundary considering Unicode
- `(xxxxx)` matches `xxxxx` as a complete word
- `(?=$|[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}])` matches a left right boundary considering Unicode
- `.*?(?=^[0-9]+\.$)` matches the smallest amount that is followed by a line with a number

But there are problems: It would work if your `xxxxx` were the exact letters you were looking for but what about the `*` and `?` you wanted to use?

Well, to handle `*` and `?` we need to take the user input (potentially including `*` and `?`) and make regex-y replacements for them:

1. Acquire the user input
2. Escape all characters special to regex with a backslash (`\`)
3. Replace `\?` with `[\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}]`
4. Replace `\*` with `[\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}]+`

Now we could insert this adjusted input where the `xxxxx` is in this regex:

`^[0-9]+\.$(?:.(?!^[0-9]+\.$))+(?<=^|[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}])(xxxxx)(?=$|[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}]).*?(?=^[0-9]+\.$)` with the flags `gmsu`

Where:

- `^[0-9]+\.$` matches a line with a number
- `(?:.(?!^[0-9]+\.$))+` matches characters that aren't followed by a line with a number
- `(?<=^|[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}])` matches a left word boundary considering Unicode
- `(xxxxx)` matches `xxxxx` as a complete word
- `(?=$|[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}])` matches a left right boundary considering Unicode
- `.*?(?=^[0-9]+\.$)` matches the smallest amount of stuff that is followed by a line with a number

But there are problems: The match groups only include the last occurrence of the input because there is only one capture group in the pattern.

Like https://stackoverflow.com/a/37004214/2193968 says:

> With one group in the pattern, you can only get one exact result in that group. If your capture group gets repeated by the pattern (you used the + quantifier on the surrounding non-capturing group), only the last value that matches it gets stored.

That means that we will only match the last occurrence even if we adjust the regex to have a repeated capture group like this:

`^[0-9]+\.$(?:(?:.(?!^[0-9]+\.$))+?(?<=^|[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}])(xxxxx)(?=$|[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}]))+.*?(?=^[0-9]+\.$)` with the flags `gmsu`

Where:

- `^[0-9]+\.$` matches a line with a number
- `(?: ... )+` matches a repeated group of:

  - `(?:.(?!^[0-9]+\.$))+` matches characters that aren't followed by a line with a number
  - `(?<=^|[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}])` matches a left word boundary considering Unicode
  - `(xxxxx)` matches `xxxxx` as a complete word
  - `(?=$|[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}])` matches a left right boundary considering Unicode
- `.*?(?=^[0-9]+\.$)` matches the smallest amount of stuff that is followed by a line with a number

There is **no** way to have the groups capture all the occurrences.

So what I recommend is:

1. Acquire the user input
2. Escape all characters special to regex with a backslash (`\`)
3. Replace `\?` with `[\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}]`
4. Replace `\*` with `[\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}]+`
5. Insert that adjusted input where the `xxxxx` is in this regex:

   `^[0-9]+\.$(?:.(?!^[0-9]+\.$))+(?<=^|[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}])xxxxx(?=$|[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}]).*?(?=^[0-9]+\.$)` with the flags `gmsu`

   To see it for the word `dziedās`, have a look at https://regex101.com/r/eEuk38/1
6. Store the resulting matches as the output.
7. Find the bold-able matches with this regex using that output:

   `(?<=^|[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}])xxxxx(?=$|[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}])` with the flags `gmsu`

   To see it for the word `dziedās`, have a look at https://regex101.com/r/I0Psxp/1

So for example:

- The input `?zied*` would become:

  `[\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}]zied[\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}]+`
- Find the verses that match with:

  `^[0-9]+\.$(?:.(?!^[0-9]+\.$))+(?<=^|[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}])[\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}]zied[\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}]+(?=$|[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}]).*?(?=^[0-9]+\.$)` with the flags `gmsu`
- Take the matches and bold the words with:

  `(?<=^|[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}])[\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}]zied[\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}]+(?=$|[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}])` with the flags `gmsu`

Comment: Thank you for detailed suggestions and explanations! They help a lot!