# How to remove symbols from string in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I want to remove all special symbols from string and have only words in string like this :

[image]

I want to displaye it inside my flutter app on chips , any solution  And thanks

Comment: Can you include sample data as string and what are you expecting as output

Comment: what the special symbols are?

Comment: I guess you are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53240710/5812524